# jQuery sliding through LIs

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a long list of LId which flow off the screen, I would like it so that when I click on the prev and next buttons the slides move along one in whichever direction is clicked. I would preferably like it to loop, I want to steer away from plugins if possible.

I know I need the marginLeft to increment its value but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<ul>
   <li class="first selected team_one"></li>
   <li class="team_two"></li>
   <li class="team_three"></li>
   <li class="team_four"></li>
   <li class="last team_five"></li>
</ul>

$('.team .next').click(function(){
   $('.team ul li.first').animate({ marginLeft: '-157px' });
});

$('.team .prev').click(function(){              
   $('.team ul li.first').animate({ marginLeft: '0' });
});
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in a total padding-left of 25px." [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Wel the idea is that is a list of elemnts one next to each other, in a div with overflow:hidden. then you just animate the left, or the margin, etc to make it go to next image, what I use is css3 transitions to animate the movement.

You can do a function with a setTimeout() of a few seconds and inside you increment margin or left (as the comment of pmandell), after the the increment you call your function again and you can place at the top an if statement like if left or margin higher than x then instead of increment you set the initial value again. you could also define a boolean and stop the animation when that boolean changes, as a counter or something like that.

Hope it helps you.